# Extract and save data from another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

In my app users create a project then create a team and invite team members by sending them a mail to sign up to the app. 
I am trying to figure out how to add the invited user to the team that was created just before. 
I tried using : TeamMember.user = user but obviously it does not work ;)
Could you help me to make it work ?

Registration/views.py:

```
def TeamRegister(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TeamMembersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            password = MyUser.objects.make_random_password()
            user.set_password(password)
            user.is_active = False
            user.is_employee = True
            TeamMember.user = user
            user.save()
            u1 = user.id
            a1 = MyUser.objects.get(email = request.user.email)
            a2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin = a1)
            a3 = a2.latest('id')
            a4 = a3.team_id
            a4.members.add(u1)
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user':user,
                'domain':current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please sign in to get access to the app'
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('An email have been sent to your user asking him to sign in')

    else:
        form = TeamMembersForm()

    return render(request, 'team_register.html', {'form': form})
```

app/models.py

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")


    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to somehow identify the Team as well. If you have the team in the view, then you can just create the `TeamMember` object as such:

```
# Just one suggestion of how this could be done, but this shouldn't work out of the box
TeamMember.objects.create(user_id=user.id,
                          team_id=Team.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['team_id']))
```

And as for your models, **please** consult Django documentation on M2M relationships in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Create a `ManyToManyField` and use the `TeamMember` as the `through` model or delete it at all, because Django generates that automatically as well.

Comment: So would you advise to delete the teammember models and add an attribute to team of teammembers ?

Comment: Because the doc says that using an intermediate model for a many-to-many relationship, may cause that some of the related manager’s methods are disabled, so some of these examples won’t work with such models.

Comment: @Ben2pop If you're not planning to add any fields to the `TeamMember` model, then I would advise to delete it, yes.

Comment: Ok I am starting to figure out and understand everything, the thing is that my worflow is, the user create a team with a name and then invite members with a form that ask only for an email and create a user (with an ID and a Mail) How to I make a reference to the Team that was just created ?

Comment: @Ben2pop Well you have to store the Team data somewhere until you start inviting members. One simple way would be to let the user select which team he/she wants to invite people to.

Comment: I manage to make it work but I am not sure that it is the good way, I edited my code from U1.. It works .. but I do not now if it is scalable.. what do you thin ?

Comment: @Ben2pop It works only if you want to invite members to the latest project every time. If the project can vary, then this will blow up in your face. I wouldn't recommend this solution.

Comment: got it, I guess you are right, My flow is user create a project then a team linked to that project and then create members for that team that are supposed to populate the team just created. So you think it is better to ask the user which team he wants to populate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154693/discussion-between-makaveli-and-ben2pop).